# Adding a view over iPhone window, even above UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I want to add a view in my `UIViewController`. The view must also cover the `UINavigationBar`. My overlay view covers the view of my app but it does not cover the navigation bar. How can I cover the navigation bar?

Comment: Please add your code with your question :)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this via adding the view on window

Create the reference of AppDelegate and use its window property for adding the subView.
   // Declare this in your .h file and then import AppDelegate.h file in your .m file

```
    id _AppDelegate;
    _AppDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[_AppDelegate window] addSubview:yourView];
```